# AWS CDK Assertions - Looking at Individual Resources In A Stack

Tags: typescript, testing, aws-cdk

**Current Situation:**

1. I have a file that has 11 different `NodejsFunction`s. I am looking to write assertions with [CDK Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_assertions.Template.html).
2. I have code that checks the whole stack, and says "Is there a Lambda handler?": `template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::Lambda::Function", { Handler: "index.handler" }))`

**Requirement:**

How do I ensure each `NodejsFunction` function has `Handler: "index.handler"` ? Can I narrow down to specific `public readonly lambdaExample: NodejsFunction` from the stack, or map over the services in the stack?

**Current Test:**

```
import { Template } from "aws-cdk-lib/assertions";
import { createStacks } from "../../bin/template";

    describe.only("lambdaStack", () => {
      let allStacks, template: Template;
      beforeAll(async () => {
        allStacks= await createStacks(true);
        template = Template.fromStack(allStacks.lambdaStack);
      });
    
      it("should have Handler = 'handler'", () => template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::Lambda::Function", { Handler: "index.handler" }));
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assert every resource has the desired property, use [allResourceProperties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions.Template.html#allwbrresourceswbrpropertiestype-props):

```js
template.allResourcesProperties("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
  Handler: "index.handler",
});
```

To assert a given resource (by Logical ID) has the desired property, filter and assert:

```js
expect(
  Object.entries(template.findResources("AWS::Lambda::Function")).filter(
    ([k, v]) =>
      k.match(/^LambdaExample[A-F0-9]{8}$/) &&
      v["Properties"]?.["Handler"] === "index.handler"
  )
).toHaveLength(1);
```