# How to write cdk test for lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function that simply queries an Athena database, formats data and sends an axios post request. I wrote some CDK files so I could have my infrastructure as code and an accompanying test. But when I run the test it fails complaining about the Node runtime version. Despite me using the same version on both the test and the lambda function.

In a nutshell I want to use the cdk to create a lambda that has permission to preform a select query on athena and have that lambda function run on a schedule of every 6 hours.

here is my code for the lambda

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

const Athena = new AWS.Athena();

interface ApiResponse {
  statusCode: number;
  body: string;
}

interface AthenaQueryResult {
  productionForecastData: Record<string, string>;
}

interface FormattedQueryResults {
  clientData: AthenaQueryResult[];
}

export const handler = async (): Promise<ApiResponse> => {
  try {
    const results = await queryAthena();
    const apiResponse = await postResultsToApi(results);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(apiResponse.data),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Internal Server Error" }),
    };
  }
};

const queryAthena = async (): Promise<FormattedQueryResults> => {
  const query = `select * from my_table limit 10`;

  const database = "database_name";

  const databaseParams: AWS.Athena.StartQueryExecutionInput = {
    QueryString: query,
    QueryExecutionContext: {
      Database: database,
    },
  };

  const { QueryExecutionId: queryExecutionId } =
    (await Athena.startQueryExecution(databaseParams).promise()) ?? {};

  const params = {
    QueryExecutionId: queryExecutionId || "",
  };

  // Wait for the query to complete
  await Athena.waitFor("queryExecutionComplete", params).promise();

  // Retrieve the results from Athena and format
  const results = await getFormattedQueryResults(params);

  console.log("Query Results:", results);

  return results;
};

const postResultsToApi = async (
  data: FormattedQueryResults
): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
  const apiEndpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT as string;
  const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN as string;
  const postData = JSON.stringify(data);

  const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `api-key ${authToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  return await axios.post(apiEndpoint, postData, axiosConfig);
};

const getFormattedQueryResults = async (
  params: AWS.Athena.GetQueryResultsInput
): Promise<FormattedQueryResults> => {
  const result: AWS.Athena.GetQueryResultsOutput = await Athena.getQueryResults(
    params
  ).promise();

  const columnInfo: AWS.Athena.ColumnInfo[] =
    result.ResultSet?.ResultSetMetadata?.ColumnInfo || [];
  const rows =
    result.ResultSet?.Rows?.map((row) => {
      const rowData: AthenaQueryResult = { productionForecastData: {} };
      row.Data?.forEach((data, index) => {
        rowData["productionForecastData"][columnInfo[index].Name] =
          data?.VarCharValue || "";
      });
      return rowData;
    }) || [];

  const data: FormattedQueryResults = {
    clientData: rows,
  };
  return JSON.stringify(data) as unknown as FormattedQueryResults;
};
```

Heres my CDK code

```
import {
  aws_iam as iam,
  aws_events as events,
  aws_lambda as lambda,
  Duration,
  aws_events_targets as targets,
  Stack,
  StackProps,
} from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { ManagedPolicy } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";

export class DatalakeToOilProductionStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create IAM role for Lambda
    const lambdaExecutionRole = new iam.Role(this, "LambdaExecutionRole", {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
      managedPolicies: [
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          "service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ),
      ],
    });

    // Attach an inline policy granting permission to Athena
    lambdaExecutionRole.addToPolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: [
          "athena:StartQueryExecution",
          "athena:GetQueryExecution",
          "athena:GetQueryResults",
        ],
        resources: ["*"], // Replace with the appropriate Athena resource ARNs if possible
      })
    );

    const datalakeToOilProductionFunction = new lambda.Function(
      this,
      "datalakeToOilProductionLambda",
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
        handler: "index.handler",
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda"), // Directory where code resides
        role: lambdaExecutionRole,
      }
    );

    const rule = new events.Rule(this, "datalakeToOilProductionSchedule", {
      schedule: events.Schedule.rate(Duration.hours(6)),
    });

    rule.addTarget(new targets.LambdaFunction(datalakeToOilProductionFunction));
  }
}
```

and finally heres my associated test

```
import { App, aws_lambda as lambda } from "aws-cdk-lib";

import * as DatalakeToOilProduction from "../lib/datalake-to-oil-production-stack";
import { Template } from "aws-cdk-lib/assertions";

test("DatalakeToOilProductionStack has the necessary resources", () => {
  const app = new App();
  const stack = new DatalakeToOilProduction.DatalakeToOilProductionStack(
    app,
    "MyTestStack"
  );

  const template = Template.fromStack(stack);
  // Test Lambda function
  template.hasResource("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
    Handler: "index.handler",
    Runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
  });

  // Test CloudWatch Events Rule
  template.hasResource("AWS::Events::Rule", {
    ScheduleExpression: "rate(6 hours)",
  });

  // Test Lambda function as target in CloudWatch Events Rule
  template.hasResource("AWS::Events::Rule", {
    Targets: [
      {
        Arn: {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["datalakeToOilProductionLambda", "Arn"],
        },
        Id: "Target0",
      },
    ],
  });

  template.hasResource("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
    Properties: {
      Role: {
        Policies: [
          {
            PolicyDocument: {
              Statement: [
                {
                  Action: [
                    "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                    "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                    "athena:GetQueryResults",
                  ],
                  Effect: "Allow",
                  Resource: "*",
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
});
```

this is my first time writing cdk any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Below is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\braiden.parkinson\Development\datalake-to-oil-production> npm test

> datalake-to-oil-production@0.1.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  test/datalake-to-oil-production.test.ts (5.859 s)
  × DatalakeToOilProductionStack has the necessary resources (381 ms)

  ● DatalakeToOilProductionStack has the necessary resources

    Template has 1 resources with type AWS::Lambda::Function, but none match as expected.
    The 1 closest matches:
    datalakeToOilProductionLambda4AF63CDC :: {
      "DependsOn": [ "LambdaExecutionRoleDefaultPolicy6D69732F", "LambdaExecutionRoleD5C26073" ],
    !! Missing key 'Handler'
      "Handler": undefined,
      "Properties": { ... },
    !! Missing key 'Runtime'
      "Runtime": undefined,
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    }

      13 |   const template = Template.fromStack(stack);
      14 |   // Test Lambda function
    > 15 |   template.hasResource("AWS::Lambda::Function", {
         |            ^
      16 |     Handler: "index.handler",
      17 |     Runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
      18 |   });

      at Template.hasResource (node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/assertions/lib/template.js:1:3240)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/datalake-to-oil-production.test.ts:15:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.98 s
Ran all test suites.
`
```

Comment: Your post is missing details of the error message and how someone can repro it.

Comment: @jarmod updated sorry

Comment: Not familiar with this, but perhaps the keys (handler and runtime) are simply mis-spelled because you wrote `Handler` and `Runtime` in your call to `template.hasResource(...)`? Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232893/aws-cdk-assertions-looking-at-individual-resources-in-a-stack) which might help.